# Wrapping output of one column

Tags: powershell

I have a script that collects information from one or more servers and displays it via passing various functions to a remote session (that are returned largely as arrays:

```
$PSSession = New-PSSession -ComputerName $comp -Credential $fetchCreds -Name $server
$buildlogsuccess = Invoke-Command -Session $pssession -ScriptBlock ${function:check-buildlog} -ArgumentList $domain
$chocologstatus = Invoke-Command -Session $pssession -ScriptBlock ${function:check-choco}
$KMSvalues = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-winlicense}
$parentOU = get-ParentOU (Get-ADComputer -Server $dc -SearchBase $searchbase -Filter {name -eq $server} -Credential $fetchCreds) | select -expand parentou
$SCCMcheck = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-sccmstatus} 
$scomcheck = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${function:get-scomstatus} -argumentlist $scom
$AV = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-avstatus}
$wfirewall = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {(get-service MpsSvc).status}
$net35 = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {(Get-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-Core).installed}
$admins = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:check-admins} 
$DomainComms = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-domaininfo}
$bigfix =  Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock ${Function:get-bigfix}
#clean up the remote session
Remove-PSSession -Name $server

[PSCustomObject]@{
    ServerName = $comp
    "Physical/Virtual" = $Devicetype
    "IP Address" = $device.IPAddresses.ipaddress
    "Domain" = $DomainComms[4]
    "Build Script Found, Completed" = [string]$buildlogsuccess[0] + [string]"," + [string]$buildlogsuccess[1]
    "Choco Package Install Finished" = $chocologstatus
    "KMS License Status, Retry" = [string]$KMSvalues[0] + [string]"," + [string]$KMSvalues[1]
    "Parent OU" = $parentOU
    "VM Tools Version, Status" = "$vmtoolsversion,$vmtoolsstatus"
    "SCCM Client, Version,Last Comms" = ([string]$SCCMcheck[0] + [string]"," + [string]$SCCMcheck[1] + [string]"," + [string]$SCCMcheck[2]) 
    "SCOM Client, Conn Status" = [string]$scomcheck[0] + [string]"," + [string]$scomcheck[1]
    "McAfee Framework Installed, Running" = [string]$AV[0] + [string]"," + [string]$AV[1]
    "McAfee Vcan Installed, DAT Date" = [string]$AV[2] + [string]"," + [string]$AV[3]
    "SEP Endpoint Protection Installed, Running" = [string]$AV[4] + [string]"," + [string]$AV[5]
    "SEP Vcan Installed, DAT Date" = [string]$AV[6] + [string]"," + [string]$AV[7]
    "BigFix Client, Version, Install Date" = [string]$bigfix[0] + [string]"," + [string]$bigfix[1] + [string]"," + [string]$bigfix[2]
    "Windows Firewall Status" = $wfirewall
    "Net 3.5 Installed" = $net35
    "Connection to domain OK, Current DC, AD Site" = [string]$DomainComms[0] + "," + [string]$DomainComms[1]  + "," + [string]$DomainComms[2]
    "DelAdmin Groups in Admins" = $admins[1]
    "Applied GPOs" = $DomainComms[3]
}
```

Output (for the most part) comes out as expected, except the last field while appearing ok in the list output and `Out-GridView`, doesn't output properly when using `Export-Csv` (or copy correctly into Excel from `Out-GridView`):

```
ServerName                                   : serverA.abc.com
Physical/Virtual                             : Virtual
IP Address                                   : 10.20.30.40
Domain                                       : abc.com
Build Script Found, Completed                : Found C:\tre\w32\Logs\Installer.log,True
Choco Package Install Finished               : False: can't find C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log
KMS License Status, Retry                    : True,N/A
BigFix Client, Version, Install Date         : False,N/A,N/A                                                            
Windows Firewall Status                      : Running
Net 3.5 Installed                            : True
Connection to domain OK, Current DC, AD Site : True,dc1.abc.com,Default-First-Site
GG_admin_serverA in Admins                    : False
DelAdmin Groups in Admins                    : abc\a-groupname-here

Applied GPOs                                 : SOE Server GPO 1
                                               SOE Server GPO 2
                                               Some-other-policy
                                               A group policy name - Infrastructure
                                               SOE Server GPO 1
                                               SOE Server GPO 2
                                               Some-other-policy
                                               A group policy name - Infrastructure
                                               SOE Server GPO 1
                                               SOE Server GPO 2
                                               Some-other-policy
                                               A group policy name - Infrastructure
```

Is a way to wrap the output of an array element when that element is multi line output such as this, be it for CSV, HTML etc.

When for instance I copy from `Out-GridView` to Excel or `Export-Csv`, the 'applied GPOs' field ends up showing values in other rows & columns outside of where it should.

Comment: Please provide samples of desired and actual CSV output (as text, not screenshots).

Comment: Again, please provide samples of desired and actual **CSV output**.

Answer (score 1):

Is this as simple as specifying that the value should be a string?

```
"Applied GPOs" = "$($DomainComms[3])"
```

Otherwise, you will need to manipulate the array to specify what character should be used between each element. Such as **`n** for new line:

```
"Applied GPOs" = $DomainComms[3] -join "`n"
```